# D3 calendar heat map. How to display number or anything in rectangles of heatmap

Tags: d3.js

All rectangles are positioning correctly. But I am trying to display count in rectangle. I tried lot of ways but it is not working. I tried by grouping the rectangle and text tag by group tag. I got the text but some how data is not coming to the text tag. I am giving a link for reference [In this heat map there displaying only heatmap with rectangles][1]. I got lot solutions but didn't worked for my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#calendar {
  margin: 20px;
}
.month {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.month-name {
  font-size: 85%;
  fill: #777;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
.day.hover {
  stroke: #6d6E70;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
.day.focus {
  stroke: #ffff33;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function drawCalendar(dateData){

  var weeksInMonth = function(month){
    var m = d3.timeMonth.floor(month)
    return d3.timeWeeks(d3.timeWeek.floor(m), d3.timeMonth.offset(m,1)).length;
  }

  var minDate = d3.min(dateData, function(d) { return new Date(d.day) })
  var maxDate = d3.max(dateData, function(d) { return new Date(d.day) })

  var cellMargin = 2,
      cellSize = 20;

  var day = d3.timeFormat("%w"),
      week = d3.timeFormat("%U"),
      format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"),
      titleFormat = d3.utcFormat("%a, %d-%b");
      monthName = d3.timeFormat("%B"),
      months= d3.timeMonth.range(d3.timeMonth.floor(minDate), maxDate);

  var svg = d3.select("#calendar").selectAll("svg")
    .data(months)
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("class", "month")
    .attr("height", ((cellSize * 7) + (cellMargin * 8) + 20) ) // the 20 is for the month labels
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      var columns = weeksInMonth(d);
      return ((cellSize * columns) + (cellMargin * (columns + 1)));
    })
    .append("g")

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "month-name")
    .attr("y", (cellSize * 7) + (cellMargin * 8) + 15 )
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      var columns = weeksInMonth(d);
      return (((cellSize * columns) + (cellMargin * (columns + 1))) / 2);
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return monthName(d); })

  var rect = svg.selectAll("rect.day")
    .data(function(d, i) { return d3.timeDays(d, new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 1)); })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "day")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("rx", 3).attr("ry", 3) // rounded corners
    .attr("fill", '#eaeaea') // default light grey fill
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (day(d) * cellSize) + (day(d) * cellMargin) + cellMargin; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellSize) + ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellMargin) + cellMargin ; })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed('hover', false);
    })
    .datum(format);

  rect.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return titleFormat(new Date(d)); });

  var lookup = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.day; })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d){ return parseInt(d.count); });
    })
    .object(dateData);

  var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(dateData, function(d) { return parseInt(d.count); }))
    .range([0.4,1]); // the interpolate used for color expects a number in the range [0,1] but i don't want the lightest part of the color scheme

  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in lookup; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d3.interpolatePuBu(scale(lookup[d])); })
    .select("title")
    .text(function(d) { return titleFormat(new Date(d)) + ":  " + lookup[d]; });

}

d3.csv("dates.csv", function(response){
  drawCalendar(response);
})


</script>
```

This is the csv

```
day,count
2016-05-12,171
2016-06-17,139
2016-05-02,556
2016-04-10,1
2016-05-04,485
2016-03-27,1
2016-05-26,42
2016-05-25,337
2016-05-23,267
2016-05-05,569
2016-03-31,32
2016-03-25,128
2016-05-13,221
2016-03-30,26
2016-03-15,3
2016-04-24,10
2016-04-27,312
2016-03-20,99
2016-05-10,358
2016-04-01,15
2016-05-11,199
2016-07-06,744
2016-05-08,23
2016-03-28,98
2016-03-29,64
2016-04-30,152
2016-03-21,148
2016-03-19,20
2016-05-07,69
2016-04-29,431
2016-04-25,330
2016-04-28,353
2016-04-18,9
2016-01-10,1
2016-01-09,2
2016-03-26,21
2016-05-27,18
2016-04-19,10
2016-04-06,1
2016-04-12,214
2016-05-03,536
2016-07-03,3
2016-06-16,1
2016-03-24,138
2016-04-26,351
2016-04-23,14
2016-05-01,19
2016-07-05,523
2016-05-22,3
2016-05-09,430
2016-05-24,472
2016-04-11,172
2016-03-17,7
2016-05-14,10
2016-05-06,449
2016-07-04,295
2016-05-15,12
2016-03-23,216
2016-03-18,47
2016-03-22,179
```